# Trying to implement a function C++

Tags: c++, function

I started learning C++ a few weeks ago. Now I'm trying to program a kind of shop as a challenge. I've made it 2 or 3 times before, but always in one program. This time I tried to put some functions I wrote in it, so the main file wouldn't be that messed up again.

The problem I'm having is, when I'm trying to import a function, I get this error message:

> E0413 There is no suitable conversion function from 'std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char>>' to 'int'.

Here's the code:

Mainfile:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "Benutzer.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    user;
}
```

Function:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int user
{
    cout << "So you're a user. What do you want to buy?"
}
```

I know it's not much code by now, but I was already testing.

Comment: Details matter when coding. You're missing a several small things in your code. You should carefully review the syntax of declaring and calling a function.

Comment: `main` is a function. So is your function. Try comparing one with the other, and see if you can spot a difference. Your C++ textbook must have many examples of calling functions. So, what can you learn from looking at those examples, and seeing how they differ from yours?

Comment: You have already defined a function (`main`), now think about that definition and how it differs from your `user` "function".

Comment: `int user { ... }` declares an `int` variable initialized with `...`, not a function that returns an `int`. And you can't initialize an `int` from the output of `cout << ...`, which is what the error message is complaining about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I can see, your program has an error in syntax.

Two things you need to consider here:

1. How to define a function:

```cpp
return_type func_name(data_type args){
/// function body
}
```

2. How to call a function:

```cpp
func_name(args);
```

I verified your code with little change on my system.

This is correct code:

***main_file.cpp***

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "Benutzer.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    user();
}
```

***Benutzer.h***

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int user()
{
    cout << "So you're a user. What do you want to buy?";
     return 0;
}
```

This works.